Redis Instance Reuse in AWS Lambda
Question:
I'm using Redis as a caching database within my AWS Lambda functions, and I have a question regarding how Redis works under the hood when reusing the same Redis client instance across different Lambda invocations.
I use a single Redis client instance to avoid creating a new connection every time a Lambda function is invoked. My concern is about the potential side effects when multiple Lambda instances are invoked simultaneously.
Scenario:

Lambda 1 starts and initiates multiple Redis operations using the multi/exec commands.
At the same time, Lambda 2 is invoked and performs a simple Redis add operation using the same Redis client instance.
If Lambda 2 completes its operation and Lambda 1 calls discard, will the discard command in Lambda 1 affect the Redis operations in Lambda 2?

My Questions:

Does reusing the same Redis client instance across different Lambda invocations cause any interference between the operations of those invocations as they share the same instance connection?
Should I create a new Redis client instance for each Lambda invocation to avoid potential conflicts?


Lambda 1 and 2 execute concurrently and do not share the same Redis client (or any other state).

@jarmod thanks. But I'm still confused about the behavior of AWS Lambda in relation to global instance sharing. As I understand, Lambda may reuse the same infrastructure context for subsequent invocations, potentially allowing them to share a global instance. Could you clarify how this impacts the isolation between concurrent Lambda function executions?

Unclear what you mean by a "global instance". May be worth reviewing Understand the Lambda execution environment lifecycle and Reuse Redis Connections across AWS Lambda invocations.

No, you don't need a separate Redis instance for each lambda invocation because:

Redis is single threaded. Meaning it will execute one command at a time. it may seems like you are running two or more commands simultaneously but they'll execute one after the another.
As mentioned here Redis transactions are atomic, which means all the commands will be executed as single operation and if any command fails it will rollback the whole transaction.

